# Show ranking of each result in an array php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, rank

I've been hitting my head on the wall all day over this one I'm sure what to do. I'm hoping it's not really simple because it's been a struggle for me! I've searched all day long hopefully someone can help me.

I have an html table that shows the fitness test results of every player from a training camp. I have figured out how to display them all along with their name (taken from another mysql table). Now beside each test result I want to add how they rank for that specific test result. Here is the code right now minus the filtering part (I don't think that it's needed to solve this):

The database query is below. It orders the players in the table by positions so that all the defence show up together, all the forwards together, and goalies together for easy viewing by a coach.

```
//get the camp id for the coach logged in
$getcampid = "SELECT value FROM profile_values WHERE uid = '$user->uid'";   
$campid = mysql_query ($getcampid);
$campidrow = mysql_fetch_array($campid);
$coachescamp = $campidrow[0];

$getplayerdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content_type_test 

INNER JOIN content_type_player ON content_type_test.field_player_uid=
content_type_player.field_uid 

WHERE content_type_test.field_training_camp_nid='$coachescamp' 

ORDER BY content_type_player.field_position_value") or die(mysql_error());

$left = true;
while($playerdata=mysql_fetch_array($getplayerdata))
{

echo "<td>", $playerdata['field_position_value'], "</td>";
echo "<td>", $playerdata['field_last_name_value'],", ",$playerdata['field_first_name_value'], "</td>";
echo "<td>", $playerdata['field_speed_value'], "</td>";
echo "<td>Show rank of players speed compared to other players in $getplayerdata query</td>";
echo "<td>", $playerdata['field_agility_value'], "</td>";
echo "<td>Show rank of players agility compared to other players in $getplayerdata query</td>";
echo"</tr>";
}
echo"</tbody></table>";
```

I need to show the rank of the players speed and agility in the columns where it says "show rank of players...". In total there are 5 more ranks that I need to display in that table that I didn't include to keep thing simple. If I can see how to do it for these two I'll be able to do it for the others.

Of note: Speed and Agility are numbers. The lowest number from the array should be ranked #1.

Thanks for any help this ones been killing me.

EDIT -------------------------------------

Here is the code I have that returns only 1 result

```
$getplayerdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content_type_test 

INNER JOIN content_type_player ON content_type_test.field_player_uid=
content_type_player.field_uid 

WHERE content_type_test.field_training_camp_nid='$coachescamp' 

ORDER BY content_type_player.field_position_value") or die(mysql_error());

$left = true;
while($playerdata=mysql_fetch_array($getplayerdata))
{

$arrayOfAllData = array();
while($playerdata=mysql_fetch_array($getplayerdata)){
$arrayOfAllData[$playerdata[ID]] = array(field_position_value =>$playerdata['field_position_value'],
                                      field_last_name_value=>$playerdata['field_last_name_value'], 
                                      field_speed_value=>$playerdata['field_speed_value']);

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank', * FROM content_type_test, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
INNER JOIN content_type_player ON content_type_test.field_player_uid=
content_type_player.field_uid 
WHERE content_type_test.field_training_camp_nid='$coachescamp' 
ORDER BY content_type_player.field_speed_value");

while($playerdata=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $arrayOfAllData[$playerdata[ID]]["field_speed_value"] = $playerdata['field_speed_value'];
}

foreach($arrayOfAllData as $player){
   echo "<td>", $player['field_position_value'], "</td>";
   echo "<td>", $player['field_last_name_value'],", ",$player['field_first_name_value'], "</td>";
   echo "<td>", $player['field_speed_value'], "</td>";
   echo "<td>*I dont know what to put here to display the rank*</td>";   
   echo"</tr>";
}
}
echo"</tbody></table>";
```

Doing the Print shows one row like this 
    Array ( [] => Array ( [field_position_value] => Forward [field_last_name_value] => Tester [field_speed_value] => 4.504 ) )

Also as noted in the one column I don't know what to type to show the rank.

Answer (score 0):

OK, since there is no elegant way to do this with 1 MySQL query, I would use multiple querys, combine them into an array and loop through that for your results.  It's a bit of a hack, but will get the job done.

Use your original query, then instead of looping through and displaying right away, loop through and put into array:

```
$arrayOfAllData = array();
while($playerdata=mysql_fetch_array($getplayerdata)){
$arrayOfAllData[$playerdata[ID]] = array(field_position_value =>$playerdata['field_position_value'],
                                          field_last_name_value=>$playerdata['field_last_name_value'], 
                                          field_speed_value=>$playerdata['field_speed_value'])

}
```

Then get your next MySQL query that will rank the players by field_speed_value

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 ‘rank’, * FROM content_type_test, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r 
INNER JOIN content_type_player ON content_type_test.field_player_uid=
content_type_player.field_uid 
WHERE content_type_test.field_training_camp_nid='$coachescamp' 
ORDER BY content_type_player.field_speed_value");
```

This query will add a ranking for each player, now you have to add this ranking as a value in the $arrayOfAllData

```
while($playerdata=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $arrayOfAllData[$playerdata[ID]]["field_speed_value"] = $playerdata['field_speed_value']);
}
```

make a new query for each ranking, and add it to your array the same way.  Then when you are all done adding to the array, you can out put like this:

```
foreach($arrayOfAllData as $player){
   echo "<td>", $player['field_position_value'], "</td>";
   echo "<td>", $player['field_last_name_value'],", ",$player['field_first_name_value'], "</td>";
....etc...
}
```

Hope this helps, Im tired and going to bed, can clarify tomorrow if you have any problems.

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time. I don't have a chance to try it out right now to see how it works but thank you for your response. If I get it working I will make sure to mark this as the answer

Comment: Thanks, let me know.  This code was not tested thoroughly, but it should work.  I did notice an error I had made when adding the ranking data to the $arrayOfAllData, the way I had done it previously would replace the entire array, I have corrected the code so that it will add the info and keep whats there intact.

Comment: I finally got a chance to play with it but it is only returning 1 player in table now and I am not sure what code I need to type to display the actual rank. I will play with it some more tonight

Comment: Make sure you are only declaring $arrayOfAllData = array(); 1 time at the beginning of the file.   What happens if you put print_r($arrayOfAllData); at the end of the file.   If you can post your new code, I can look at it and see why you are only getting 1 row back.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: SORRY - This Query will only work in SQL Server, not MySQL.

you can add columns to your sql query that will have the rankings:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY field_speed_value) AS field_speed_Ranking,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY field_agility_value) AS field_agility_Ranking
FROM content_type_test
INNER JOIN content_type_player ON content_type_test.field_player_uid=   
content_type_player.field_uid 
WHERE content_type_test.field_training_camp_nid='$coachescamp' 
ORDER BY content_type_player.field_position_value") or die(mysql_error());
```

This will give you two new columns in your query results, field_speed_Ranking and field_agility_Ranking with each player ranked in order.  Just echo them out the same way you did with the other columns.

Comment: Did you notice that OP uses MySQL?

Comment: I mainly use SQL Server, wasn't aware MySQL couldn't do this.  Will write a new query for MySQL that does something similar.  Unless OP wants to convert to Windows and install MS SQL Server???

Comment: I've heard about workarounds, but `ROW_NUMBER()` and `OVER()` aren't native. They might be interested in SQL Server, but the question is tagged `mysql`, so I believe that they expect the query to work in MySQL. :)